# Unable to map repositories

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I'm using the advanced mapping mode in Spring Data Neo4j. When I try to expose my repositories with Spring data REST, I'm getting the exception messages below. Check out [my GitHub project](https://github.com/TimmyStorms/spring-data-neo4j-example/tree/master/sdn).

```
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
Mapped "{[/{repository}/schema],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/schema+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.listEntitiesCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getSingleEntity(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putEntity(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteEntity(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchEntity(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.listEntities(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postEntity(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<?>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{method}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
```

**Spring configuration file**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan("com...")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = { "com..." })
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class SDNConfiguration extends Neo4jAspectConfiguration {

    public SDNConfiguration() {
        setBasePackage("com...");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db");
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutionEngine executionEngine() {
        return new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>            </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com...SDNConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm using:

- SDN 3.0.1.RELEASE
- Neo4j 2.0.1
- Spring Data REST 2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

I know a it´s little late but after facing the same problem i would like to share my experience:

The log is a little misleading. It doesn´t mean there are exceptions thrown while mapping the repositories. The log means simply "a repository is mapped with this method signature".

So, if there is no rest-method available there is another configuration-problem in your project.